# Impulse response $h[n]$ of a non linear I/O equation

Tags: noise, impulse-response, homework, non-linear

my question concerns an assignment that was given to us at school.
We have been given a list of I/O equations and it is required, for each of them, to find the impulse response $h[n]$ and the ratio between the variance of the input noise and the variance of the output one, namely $\frac{\sigma_{y_v}^2}{\sigma_v^2}$
, assuming that the output consists of the signal $y[n]$ and a superimposed noise $y_v[n]$, i.e:

$$y[n] + y_v[n]$$

Same for the input, which is:

$$x[n] + v[n], \quad \text{where $v[n]$ is white noise, that generates $y_v[n]$}$$

This list also includes the following equation:

$$y[n]=x[n]^2$$
My first reaction was that $h[n]$ in this case does not exist since this equation does not describe a **LTI** (Linear Time Invariant) System. Furthermore, if we consider the noise at the input, we can not say that the output is simply equal to $y[n]+y_v[n]$, because of the non linearity of the latter. We would instead have:

$$\big(x[n] + v[n]\big)^2 = x[n]^2 + v[n]^2 + 2x[n]v[n] = y[n] + y_v[n] + 2x[n]v[n]$$

My question is whether my answer is complete or there is a more formal way of answering at a mathematical level.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The system $y[n] = x^2[n]$ is nonlinear, and does not have an impulse reponse $h[n]$, you are right.

Comment: @Fat32 every system that has an impulse in its domain has an impulse response. But only for linear or even also time-invariant systems it's guaranteed to be useful for constructing the output from the input. In fact, there are even non-linear systems that can be simplified by finding the impulse response(s). So your comment is misleading at best.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are correct that there is no transfer function, because the system is nonlinear
2. Your suggested approach to finding the statistics of $x$ won't work, because the definition is circular.  There *are* methods for finding the probability density function of a function of another random variable.